# Drawing blurred lines with Matplotlib / Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, textures, glyph

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a visualization like the one below using **Matplotlib**.

[image]

Another view:

[image]

Source: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1961832

Which these images do and what I would like to do is to combine two visualizations. One (the background) is a simple plot that can be done with **imshow**, **pcolor**, **pcolormesh**, but the other one uses a texture of a grid which blur (the **w** factor) determines some characteristic, in this case, the uncertainty. Which I don't know how to do is to plot different lines with different blur. For each pixel, I have an uncertainty and I should draw a line in this pixel with the uncertainty represented as the line blur.

> I don't know how to do this latter (draw the lines with blur)  with **Matplotlib**.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question correctly. Could it be solved by doing a heat-map using pcolormesh and then drawing black lines forming the grid with alpha values corresponding to your uncertainty?

Comment: I don't see anything that would stop you doing this. It would be a bit messy to get all the lines to match up, but there are tools in there to do all of this, i've used them.

Comment: Yes, I am confident that my proposed solution can work. I am less certain if I am solving the correct problem.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, @Christoph. Not sure how to do that, though.

Comment: More specifically, the part of drawing the lines.

Comment: This is somewhat tricky to achieve. You need to add each line as a LineCollection. These are composed of individual segments consisting of start and end point. Segments can be assigned individual colors, which may contain alpha values.

Comment: @Christoph - It is doable. I'm working up an example now. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/oVkmQVP.png)'s the current progress.

Comment: On a side note - having only looked at the portions of the artical you've provided - what is the point of this? I get that the fabric pattern is being blended over the top of the `contourf` image, but from the looks of things, it is just a cross hatch pattern blended acording to the value of the underlying image. It doesn't look like it's providing any extra information. What are you looking to show with these plots?

Comment: Hi, @will. I working with uncertainty quantification and I have to plot the uncertainty of two scalar fields in a single plot (they are related, so I should provide a combined visualization besides two single ones). A common approach is to show the uncertainty of a data as saturation and the uncertainty of the other one with a pattern (blurred in uncertain points) -- this is the one that I'm trying to do with Matplotlib. Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon Ah, okay. So essentially, you have 4 data sets, A, B, and the uncertainties on each? Can you not merge the two together using the uncertainties as relative opacities?

Comment: Hi, @will. I have to data sets, A and B, and I have to show the uncertainty of both of them in a same plot (the data of them are linked, there is a relation between them I and have to provide a way to see then in a single plot). One using opacity, and the other one using some kind of pattern. :S

Comment: @pceccon could you send me two two of your data sets, along with their uncertainties? I'll see if i can craft a function to plot what you want using the `agg_filter` stuff.

Comment: Of course, @will. I put an example here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ped312ur604357r/AACQGloHDAy8I2C6HITFzjqza. The data are 20 x 20. Thank you very much for your time and for your willingness to help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well here's what i have so far - i went off on a bit of a tangent replicating `fig. 2`.

Will update tomorrow. (the first half is just to create some data)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib

def smooth1d(x, window_len):
    s=np.r_[2*x[0]-x[window_len:1:-1],x,2*x[-1]-x[-1:-window_len:-1]]
    w = np.hanning(window_len)
    y=np.convolve(w/w.sum(),s,mode='same')
    return y[window_len-1:-window_len+1]

def smooth2d(A, sigma=3):
    window_len = max(int(sigma), 3)*2+1
    A1 = np.array([smooth1d(x, window_len) for x in np.asarray(A)])
    A2 = np.transpose(A1)
    A3 = np.array([smooth1d(x, window_len) for x in A2])
    A4 = np.transpose(A3)

    return A4

class BaseFilter(object):
    def prepare_image(self, src_image, dpi, pad):
        ny, nx, depth = src_image.shape
        #tgt_image = np.zeros([pad*2+ny, pad*2+nx, depth], dtype="d")
        padded_src = np.zeros([pad*2+ny, pad*2+nx, depth], dtype="d")
        padded_src[pad:-pad, pad:-pad,:] = src_image[:,:,:]

        return padded_src#, tgt_image

    def get_pad(self, dpi):
        return 0

    def __call__(self, im, dpi):
        pad = self.get_pad(dpi)
        padded_src = self.prepare_image(im, dpi, pad)
        tgt_image = self.process_image(padded_src, dpi)
        return tgt_image, -pad, -pad

class GaussianFilter(BaseFilter):
    "simple gauss filter"
    def __init__(self, sigma, alpha=0.5, color=None):
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.alpha = alpha
        if color is None:
            self.color=(0, 0, 0)
        else:
            self.color=color

    def get_pad(self, dpi):
        return int(self.sigma*3/72.*dpi)


    def process_image(self, padded_src, dpi):
        #offsetx, offsety = int(self.offsets[0]), int(self.offsets[1])
        tgt_image = np.zeros_like(padded_src)
        aa = smooth2d(padded_src[:,:,-1]*self.alpha,
                      self.sigma/72.*dpi)
        tgt_image[:,:,-1] = aa
        tgt_image[:,:,:-1] = self.color
        return tgt_image


from matplotlib.artist import Artist

class FilteredArtistList(Artist):
    """
    A simple container to draw filtered artist.
    """
    def __init__(self, artist_list, filter):
        self._artist_list = artist_list
        self._filter = filter
        Artist.__init__(self)

    def draw(self, renderer):
        renderer.start_rasterizing()
        renderer.start_filter()
        for a in self._artist_list:
            a.draw(renderer)
        renderer.stop_filter(self._filter)
        renderer.stop_rasterizing()





##Create the landscape
from noise import snoise2

def boxOnSurface(rect, X,Y,Z):
  #Make rectangle of indicies to draw. Left the four loops expanded for clarity. Otherwise it's fairly ugly.
  rXs, rYs, rZs = [],[],[]

  for j in range(rect[0][1], rect[1][1]):
    i = rect[0][0]

    rXs.append(X[i][j])
    rYs.append(Y[i][j])
    rZs.append(Z[i][j])

  for i in range(rect[0][0], rect[1][0]):
    j = rect[1][1]

    rXs.append(X[i][j])
    rYs.append(Y[i][j])
    rZs.append(Z[i][j])

  for j in range(rect[1][1], rect[0][1], -1):
    i = rect[1][0]

    rXs.append(X[i][j])
    rYs.append(Y[i][j])
    rZs.append(Z[i][j])

  for i in range(rect[1][0], rect[0][0]-1, -1):
    j = rect[0][1]

    rXs.append(X[i][j])
    rYs.append(Y[i][j])
    rZs.append(Z[i][j])

  return rXs, rYs, rZs, [np.mean(rXs), np.mean(rYs), np.mean(rZs)]



octaves = 4
freq = octaves * 100


xs, ys = np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 100), np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)

Z1 = np.zeros(X.shape)


for i,x in enumerate(xs):
  for j,y in enumerate(ys):
    Z1[i][j] = int(snoise2(x/freq, y/freq, octaves) * 127.0 + 128.0)



# get some different colours for the surface.
faceValues = np.zeros(X.shape)

noise = []

for i,x in enumerate(xs):
  for j,y in enumerate(ys):
    faceValues[i][j] = snoise2(4*x/freq, 4*y/freq, octaves)

jet = cm.get_cmap("jet")
faceColours = []


for i,x in enumerate(xs):
  faceColours.append([])
  for j,y in enumerate(ys):
    normalised = (faceValues[i][j] - faceValues.min()) / (faceValues.max() - faceValues.min())
    faceColours[i].append(jet(normalised))
    faceValues[i][j] = normalised




fig = plt.figure()
miniPlotCount = 5
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5, miniPlotCount)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4,:], projection='3d')

miniAxes = []
for i in range(miniPlotCount):
  miniAxes.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[4,i]))

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2, cstride=2, rstride=2, facecolors=faceColours, vmin=0, vmax=1)


#This decides where we draw the rectangle to be inspecting.
rect = ((25,45),(65,70))

boxXs, boxYs, boxZs, middleOfBox = boxOnSurface(rect, X,Y,Z1)
ax.plot(boxXs, boxYs, boxZs)

xb, yb, zb = middleOfBox

xPoint, yPoint, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(xb, yb, zb, ax.get_proj())


labels = []
grids = []
for i in range(miniPlotCount):
  bbox = miniAxes[i].get_window_extent()
  xytext = ((bbox.min[0] + bbox.max[0])/2, (bbox.min[1] + bbox.max[1])/2)
  labels.append(ax.annotate("", xy=(xPoint,yPoint), arrowprops = {"arrowstyle":'->', "connectionstyle":'arc3,rad=0'}, textcoords="figure pixels", xytext=xytext))

#  miniAxes[i].contourf(X[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]], Y[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]], Z1[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]])#, vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z1.max())
  miniAxes[i].contourf(X[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]], Y[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]], faceValues[rect[0][0]:rect[1][0],rect[0][1]:rect[1][1]], vmin=faceValues.min(), vmax=faceValues.max())

# miniAxes[i].set_agg_filter(gaussFilter)
  gaussFilter = GaussianFilter(i)
  miniAxes[i].grid(linestyle="-", linewidth=2, agg_filter=gaussFilter)






def update_position(e):
    xPoint, yPoint, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(xb, yb, zb, ax.get_proj())
    for label in labels:
      label.xy = xPoint, yPoint
      label.update_positions(fig.canvas.renderer)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', update_position)




plt.show()
```

Which creates this:

[image]

That has blurred grid lines. (i'm not sure why it has not blurred two of them) It appears that you can set the `agg_filter` of any object you graw in matplotlib by just adding in the `agg_filter=` kwarg. If you edited the `GaussianFilter` class, you could make it so it recieves all the uncertainty data, and then uses that to apply blur / opactiy / whatever to the various parts of the image.

Comment: I just ran across this bit of "ancient history" and I may give something like this a try. It's always okay to accept one's own answer. *Thanks!*